# Using a variable with many values for a database query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing this difficulty. This works for me :

```
<% cat_st = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29 %>
<%= Categories.where(cat_id: [cat_st]).distinct.count(:af_id) %>
```

However, I need to create the cat_st string from my GET parameters. When I create it as a string, it gets only the first integer. Actually, I really don't know what the cat_st variable is. I tried to create an array, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

( it doesn't work)

```
<% cat_st = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29' %>
<%= Categories.where(cat_id: [cat_st]).distinct.count(:af_id) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat_st = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29'

cat_array = cat_st.split(',')
Categories.where(cat_id: cat_array).distinct.count(:af_id)
```

There may be a better solution for what you're trying to achieve if you give some additional details about what you're trying to do, seems like it should be some sort of search form that passes multiple ids. Something like this for example:

```
class Search
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :category_ids
end

<%= form_for Search.new, url: 'whatever_the_url_is' do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_ids %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>

search = Search.new(search_params)
Categories.where(cat_id: search.category_ids).distinct.count(:af_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass just a range to the `where` method so:

```
Categories.where(cat_id: (1..29)).distinct.count(:af_id)
```

and to pass data via **GET** request just use a limitation:

> http://host.domain/controller/action?begin=1&end=29

controller:

```
def action
   @cat = Categories.where(cat_id: (params[:begin].to_i..params[:end].to_i)).distinct.count(:af_id)
end
```

then render the view using `@cat` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you add square brackets to the param name in the URL query, Rails (specfically Rack) will interpret that as an array:

```
http://some.route.url/path?foo[]=bar&foo[]=buzz
```

The controller will read `params[:foo]` as `['bar', buzz']`

However, I have a feeling that use case problem you are attempting to solve might have a much simpler solution.  Care to go into any more detail?